# How to call a method from a certain component in another component

Tags: next.js

I am new to NextJs and I am working on this project.
I have two components. I want to call a method of the first component from the second component. How can I do it?

This is first page.

```
const Home: NextPage = () => { 
    const router = useRouter();
    const exportPdf = () => {
        const input = document.getElementById("scorecard")!;
        html2canvas(input).then(canvas => {
            
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
            const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 450, 450);
            pdf.save('result.pdf');

        })
        
    };
    return (
        <div className='scorecard-container' id="scorecard>
                   <button className="scr-primary " onClick={exportPdf} >                    
                            <a >
                                Save and Download
                            </a>                       
                    </button>
        </div>
         

    )
}

    
};

export default Home
```

And I want to use exportPdf function in below Download element of td in below page. I tried some of the methods but nothing is working for me.
This is second page.

```
const Home: NextPage = () => { 
const router = useRouter();
 const exportPdf = () => { 
const input = document.getElementById("scorecard")!;
 html2canvas(input).then(canvas => {
const Home: NextPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <>
            <div className='table-container'>
                    
                        <table className="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" className='result_head'>Name</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Experience</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Score</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Interviewer</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th className='table_head'>Laura Norda</th>
                                    <td>0000 000 000</td>
                                    <td>16</td>
                                    <td>84</td>
                                    <td>Krishnanunny Mangalasseri</td>
                                    <td>July 29, 2022</td>
                                    <td><a  >Selected</a></td>

                                    <td >Download</td>
                                </tr>
                              
                            </tbody>
                    </table>              
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default Home
```

Comment: If you simply want to re-use a function, then move it to a separate helper file and import it into both components.

Answer (score 0):

one of the most simple way to share logic in React is to use [Context](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/context.html). In case of Next.js you can create PdfContext for example and call ... inside your _app.js to share the logic(function, states) to all component inside your application.
If your new with Next.js you can read [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) to see how to create custom _app.js.